# Play Button does not restart MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-button, playback

I click on the button to play the music is playing, click the stop button, but when I stand Clicking the play button will not play again

Code:

```
final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.shaver);
final Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

ImageButton img = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds
        v.vibrate(120000);  

        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
});

Button durdur = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dur);
durdur.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        mediaPlayer.stop();

        v.cancel();
    }
});
```

Comment: can you please add more details clearly. such as what is happening when you click button and post stack trace

Answer (score 1):

You should review the state diagram provided in the [`MediaPlayer` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html). You cannot go directly from the stopped state to the started state.

You need to call `prepare()` or `prepareAsync()` before you can start it again. From the documentation:

> Calling stop() stops playback and causes a MediaPlayer in the Started,
>   Paused, Prepared or PlaybackCompleted state to enter the Stopped
>   state.
>
> - Once in the Stopped state, playback cannot be started until
>     prepare() or prepareAsync() are called to set the MediaPlayer object
>     to the Prepared state again.